# How to model properly N:N:1 ternary relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am working on ER model which includes this ternary relationship. I know that one of the options for modeling this type of relationship is to transform that relationship to a weak entity and then connect that entity with the other three entities using a binary relationship.

How do I connect them, and with what type of binary relationship?

[N:N:1 ternary model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjn12.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE STUDY (

    STUDENT_ID int REFERENCES STUDENT,
    SUBJECT_ID int REFERENCES SUBJECT,
    DEPARTMENT_ID int NOT NULL REFERENCES DEPARTMENT,

    PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID, SUBJECT_ID)

);
```

Look how we have a primary key **not** spanning all columns. The DEPARTMENT_ID is omitted from the primary key, meaning we can:

- have various STUDENT_ID/SUBJECT_ID combinations (in multiple rows),
- but we can have only one DEPARTMENT_ID for the given STUDENT_ID/SUBJECT_ID combination (simply because one row can contain only one DEPARTMENT_ID).

To put it slightly differently: given student can study given subject only once, and this happens under a particular department.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an extra  relation R (studnr, subjectnr, departementnr)
Since only one instance of every department can be used once in this relationship due to the 1:N:N constraint, the departmentnr should be the only primary key attribute.

Comment: Pleaes use standard spelling & punctuation. PS "only one instance of every department can be used" That is not what the 1 means. See the accepted answer.